# LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: c++, библиотеки, компоновщик

Знаю что много раз эта ошибка всплывала, но я всё равно не пойму как её решить. С С++ у меня тяжело, в основном пишу на c#.

Есть проект библиотеки, к нему подключено:

```
#include <first.h>
#include <second.h>
```

Вызываю методы с них и получаю кучу `error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ`

Насколько я понимаю, ошибка заключается в том, что в .h файлах методы есть, а где именно их тело брать не видит. Надо как-то указать .lib файлы.

В .cpp файле добавил

```
#pragma comment(lib, "firstLibrary.LIB") 
#pragma comment(lib, "secondLibrary.LIB")
```

В свойствах проекта в "Каталоги включения" и "Дополнительные каталоги библиотек" указал все пути к файлам. В "дополнительные зависимости" указал эти библиотеки. Ошибка сохраняется.

Если целевую платформу сменить на x86, то библиотека без проблем собирается. Надо именно x64, т.к. стороннее ПО, куда я подсовываю библиотеку, не хочет принимать её, грешу именно на битность.

Comment: Если вы указали все библиотеки, их пути и зависимости проекта, то их можно не подключать в ручную. Может быть множество разных проблем. Лучше же конечно собрать с библиотеками, которые собраны под архитектуру программы. А уже потом идти дальше и смотреть сигнатуры имён, правильность экспорта и импорта и тд.

Comment: Кажется, вы тут уже все сами расписали. Проверить битность библиотек можно посредством утилиты dumpbin

Comment: "*Если целевую платформу сменить на x86, то библиотека без проблем собирается*" - ну естественно, попробуйте библиотеки для x64. Это же разные виды приложений...

Comment: @VTT, не знал про dumpbin. И правда, библиотека оказалась x86.